# Save figure with its frame, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How should I save a figure containing also its frame?

#### From this code;

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

my_list = [random.uniform(0.75, 1.25) for i in range(1000)]

mpl.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2.5
my_fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 7), linewidth=5, facecolor='gold', edgecolor='gray')

plt.plot(my_list, label = 'My label',color = 'r',  lw = 2.5)

plt.grid()
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('\n Y_axis [kPa] \n\n',fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('\n X_axis [w] \n',fontsize=14)
plt.ylim([0,2])
plt.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=12)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=12)

plt.savefig("test.png")

plt.show()
```

#### I expect this figure;

[image]

#### But I get it without frame;

[image]

#### Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savefig` will not honour the figure's face and edge colors but you can set them explicitly in the call.

```
plt.savefig('test.png', facecolor=my_fig.get_facecolor(),         
            edgecolor=my_fig.get_edgecolor())
```